# JDialog only load at the end of the program

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jdialog

I am using a JDialog for a project, which is load when I click on a button located inside a JFrame.

This JDialog is supposed to display an image, but the image appears only when the code called by the JFrame class is executed. My problem is that I want the image to be displayed when I call it, not at the end of my programm.

Here is my code of the JDialog :

```
public class LoadingWindow {

    private JDialog dialog;
    
    public LoadingWindow() {
        this.dialog = new JDialog();
        this.dialog.setDefaultCloseOperation(JDialog.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
        this.dialog.setTitle("Veuillez patienter");
        this.dialog.setSize(300, 200);
        URL url = LoadingWindow.class.getResource("/images/wait.gif");
        ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon(url);
        JLabel imageLabel = new JLabel();
        imageLabel.setIcon(icon);
        imageLabel.setHorizontalAlignment(JLabel.CENTER);
        imageLabel.setVerticalAlignment(JLabel.CENTER);
        this.dialog.getContentPane().add(imageLabel);
        this.dialog.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        this.dialog.setVisible(true);
    }
    
    public void stop() {
        this.dialog.dispose();
    }
}
```

Inside my JFrame, I call the JDialog this way :

```
MyJDialog mjd = new MyJDialog ();
[CODE]
mjd.stop();
```

Thanks !

Comment: Don't block the EDT (Event Dispatch Thread).  The GUI will 'freeze' when that happens.  See [Concurrency in Swing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/) for details and the fix.

Comment: So when I call my class "LoadingWindow" from another class, I block the EDT, right ?

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example of a GUI that opens a JDialog.

[image: JDialog GUI]

Here's the image I used.

[image: Car Image]

I create a `JFrame` and a `JPanel` with a `JButton`.  The `JButton` has an `ActionListener` that opens a `JDialog`.  The `JDialog` displays the car image.

Here's the complete runnable code I used.

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Image;
import java.awt.Rectangle;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.io.IOException;

import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JDialog;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class JDialogTest implements Runnable {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new JDialogTest());
    }

    private JFrame frame;

    @Override
    public void run() {
        frame = new JFrame("JDialog Test");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        frame.add(createMainPanel());

        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    private JPanel createMainPanel() {
        JPanel panel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
        panel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(
                150, 100, 150, 100));
        panel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(400, 400));

        JButton button = new JButton("Open JDialog");
        button.addActionListener(new ButtonListener());
        panel.add(button);

        return panel;
    }

    public class ButtonListener implements ActionListener {

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            new CalculateDecor(frame, "Spash Screen");
        }

    }

    public class CalculateDecor extends JDialog {

        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

        public CalculateDecor(JFrame frame, String title) {
            super(frame, true);
            Image image = getImage();
            
            setDefaultCloseOperation(DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
            setTitle(title);

            JPanel panel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());

            JLabel label = new JLabel();
            label.setHorizontalAlignment(JLabel.CENTER);
            label.setIcon(new ImageIcon(image));
            panel.add(label);

            add(panel);
            pack();
            setLocationRelativeTo(frame);
            setVisible(true);

            System.out.println(getDecorationSize());
        }

        private Dimension getDecorationSize() {
            Rectangle window = getBounds();
            Rectangle content = getContentPane().getBounds();
            int width = window.width - content.width;
            int height = window.height - content.height;
            return new Dimension(width, height);
        }
        
        private Image getImage() {
            try {
                return ImageIO.read(getClass().getResourceAsStream(
                        "/car.jpg"));
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                return null;
            }
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: Hi ! Sorry for the delay, and thanks for your answer. I'm not familiar at all with the Runnable interface, but basically, everything rely on the invokeLater or invokeAndWait method ?

Comment: @VassiliKan: Yes.  Swing is single-threaded and all Swing components must be created and executed on the [Event Dispatch Thread](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/dispatch.html).  I created a JDialog that blocks the execution of the rest of the ActionListener code.